Best way to alias customization point objects
Lets imagine that we want to create alias for customization point object, like std::ranges::advance.
Is there a good way to do this with minimal overhead?
The following code fails in VS19 because it requires deleted copy constructor:
static constexpr auto advance_my = std::ranges::advance
The following code works in all 3 compilers (MSVC, LLVM, GCC) - Godbolt. But is this the best we can do?
static constexpr auto& advance_my = std::ranges::advance
Or should we just wrap standard function with perfect forwarding wrapper that has our special name?
Update:
Basically what I want to achieve with this aliasing is to make this _IterOps struct usable on other compilers/STLs, it is used to abstract some libc++ algorithms like std::sort from input container type, so that std::sort, and std::ranges::sort uses the same implementation of sort:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__algorithm/iterator_operations.h#L49
As you can see it requires me to alias some operations for std::ranges, and in case of normal iterators we define those operations almost from scratch.

"The following code fails in MSVC because it requires deleted copy constructor:": Works form in https://godbolt.org/z/hY3Ke5j6s.

Both approaches should be guaranteed to work, except that I can't find anything that the copy construction is guaranteed to work with constexpr. But I think that is unintentional.

MSVC made std::ranges::advance copyable in VS 2022 17.9. However, the standard never specifies that std::ranges::advance is an object. In theory, it can be a magic compiler-specific thingy.

@cpplearner https://eel.is/c++draft/customization.point.object says (indirectly) that it has to be an object and also that it has to be copyable with the intuitive semantics.

Nevermind, std::ranges::advance isn't a customization point object. So the question doesn't make sense as stated.

if all you want is a alias for the object, isnt it easy to use #define ? or am i missing something here?

@ShreeyashShrestha, no, macro definitions is not good enough for me. It does not work together with template magic.

Like many questions asking about what's the "best" way to do something, you don't seem to define your criteria for judging the solutions. So when you ask, "But is this the best we can do?" it isn't clear what it falls short of.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, as with any C++ related question it is about performance overhead and conciseness of the implementation.

static constexpr auto& advance_my = std::ranges::advance looks great.
References are supposed to be aliases.
